# Ubuntu 13.04 indicator-datetime-service loads 100% CPU

Tags: gnome, services

Ubuntu 13.04 64bits desktop (freshly downloaded from the site a couple of days ago)

```
    indicator-datetime-service
```

loads CPU up to 100%( 1-2 core)

and

```
   gnome-settings-daemon
```

eats whole RAM just after Ubuntu loading.

How to fix it?

There is a bug in dev forums but it is not clear for me how to fix it (just applied a new update to the system - no way).

Deleting files from ~/.cache/; or reboot; or login with 'gnome-fallback'- no help. Even if I kill gnome-settings-daemon it may arise again later.

Note: I have a VNC4 server running on Ubuntu and gnome-core(GNOME Shell 3.6.3.1).

Note: I removed  ntpdate but no help. Calendar on desktop is inactive for some time, network time is off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in [Ubuntu Bug #774071](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-datetime/+bug/774071/comments/48), in my case it helped to substitute default dependency of `geoclue-provider` virtual package.

#### My Solution

I installed `geoclue-ubuntu-geoip` package to replace the existing
`geoclue-yahoo` package (which I uninstalled).

Probably the Yahoo Maps admins noticed high load of their geolocation service or maybe their devs changed something, which resulted in `geoclue-yahoo` not working correctly.

For this work I've used a text-mode package manager:

```
aptitude
```

Because I know it handles missing dependencies quite well and suggests solutions, for example to install one of packages to satisfy some dependency.

One can also use a graphical package manager:

```
synaptic
```

To select any other package that is listed in `geoclue-provider` - and there are many:

```
geoclue-ubuntu-geoip
geoclue-gypsy
geoclue-gsmloc
geoclue-gpsd
geoclue-yahoo
geoclue-skyhook
geoclue-plazes
geoclue-manual
geoclue-localnet
geoclue-hostip
geoclue-geonames
```

Answer (score 0):

We have found only one so solution far :

```
  sudo apt-get remove gnome-settings-daemon
```

Another option - rename gnome-settings-daemon service

Comment: I ran this and ended up without gnome.

Comment: Frederico is right, this will remove part of your gnome installation.