# Ubuntu 16.10 sluggish after login

Tags: indicator, freeze

I recently reinstalled Ubuntu 16.10 64-bit on my laptop and after a couple days of normal operation I have a weird problem. When I log in under my primary user profile after about ten seconds the system becomes so sluggish that it appears frozen. If I start a guest session or use another user profile instead the issue does not materialize at all.

**How can I resolve this slowness without a fresh reinstall or giving up on my primary user profile?** Is there any way to restore to an older state of the machine?

*Details so far:*
The only reason I know it's not completely frozen is because if I use the trackpad the mouse cursor will eventually move, though heavily delayed and stuttering. Ubuntu does respond as expected when I use  Ctrl+Alt+PrtScn REISUB.

In those ten seconds if I open a terminal and run `top` I consistently see indicator-datet (which I assume is indicator-datetime or indicator-datetime-service) rise to 100% of my CPU until the sluggishness takes over. If I try to kill it the sluggishness kicks in immediately.

*Edit 1:* Here's `free` and `df` under a guest session. I'll get the same from my main profile next, but expect a cell phone picture since I won't have time to save a screenshot.

[image: free and df under guest session]

*Edit 1 part deux:* Here's the same under my main profile. Bonus, there's the way `top` looks after the sluggishness kicks in as well.

[image: free and df under main profile]

[image: top under main profile]

*Edit 2:* Results of `tail`:

[image: tail under main profile]

Comment: I found [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/298388/ubuntu-13-04-indicator-datetime-service-loads-100-cpu), which I thought might be relevant at first, but now I doubt it.

Comment: @rclocher3 Checked Synaptic Package Manager under a guest session and I'm already set up the way the solution said to be.

Comment: Have you edited your .profile or .bashrc files? How much RAM do you have? How much swap? Show us the output of the `free` command, and the `df` command, in terminal.

Comment: @heynnema No, I haven't edited .profile or .bashrc. I'll post the results as an edit to my question.

Comment: Log into your normal account, and then immediately open the `terminal` app from the Unity dashboard, maximize the window, then type `tail -f /var/log/syslog`. This will scroll the most current entries in syslog in the terminal. Look for anything that looks suspicious, especially right when the system gets sluggish. `control-c` to exit.

Comment: ps: after the system gets sluggish, do the `top` command again, and note the `%MEM` column, and observe how high the value for indicator-datetime gets.

Comment: @heynnema I added the results of `tail` above but I'm inexperienced enough that I'm not sure what seems "suspicious". The time sync to ntp.ubuntu.com did pique my interest, though. Also, unfortunately the system gets so slow that it generally doesn't respond to keyboard commands or mouse clicks so breaking `tail` or running `top` just isn't going to happen.

Comment: Open `terminal`, and type `sudo mkdir /var/cache/samba`. See if that makes any difference after a reboot.

Comment: @heynnema Is that something that could be done effectively from a guest session or another user profile?

Comment: Try your normal login, otherwise use the root account.

Comment: @heynnema `mkdir: cannot create directory 'var/cache/samba': File exists`

Comment: Do a `ls -al /var/cache` and look for `drwxr-xr-x  3 root   root   4.0K Nov 26 08:20 samba/`. Compare it to what I show. Also, you need to edit your question so they can take it off of hold status.

Comment: @heynnema Mine's set to `drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Nov 26 12:31 samba`. And thanks for the heads up, I haven't been paying attention to anything but the comments :\ .

Comment: Could you please post text files, dialogue messages, and program output listings as text, not as images? To achieve the latter two you can either 1) select, copy & paste the dialogue text or terminal content or 2) [save the program output to a file](//askubuntu.com/q/420981/175814) and use that. Longer listings (>100 lines) should be uploaded to a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) and linked to in the question. Thanks.

Comment: Any further troubleshooting that we could do here would be very lengthy, and almost impossible. You'll have to tinker on your own. I'd recommend looking into something that's in your top level directory, that's causing the problem. I'd look at .profile, .config folder, .local folder, .bashrc, and .cache folder. Good luck!

Comment: I wanted to post this as a conclusion just in case other people come across this issue.  11/26 was the last time I was able to dedicate any time to resolving my problem and it is currently 12/4. I finally decided to just reinstall Ubuntu but when I logged into my main account one last time just to check the issue seems to have resolved itself without any additional work on my part. The only thing I can think of is that I created another admin account, used that to do some of what @heynnema suggested, and then performed a normal shut down. Maybe it was just the normal shutdown that helped. :\

Comment: Were you, or are you, trying to mount some network shares via /etc/fstab?

Comment: @heynnema I was not.

Comment: Well, I'm glad it's working for you now!

Comment: @heynnema Me too! Thanks for all your help on this. If nothing else it was a good learning experience.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue after an upgrade from 16.04 to 16.10. As a workaround, I have disabled the indicator-datetime and it seems to work (I just can't see the time anymore, but it's a minor annoyance). To disable it, "System Settings -> Date and Time -> Clock tab -> uncheck Show clock in the menu bar checkbox". I don't understand why it does it only with one of my users, but not with other users on the same computer (linked to a user setting?). I have found other people with the same issue in much older versions of Ubuntu. So a recurring bug ?